# C# connecting to a database

Tags: c#, sql, solaris

I Am Trying to create a program using c# that needs to connect to a database running on a Solaris server, I am not too familiar with the server, we normally use dbVisualizer to connect to it. the driver it uses to connect is mysql-connector-java-5.1.10, which is a jdbc driver. was wondering what drivers to use to connect to the database using C# and what is the syntax used to establish the connection. as far as I know I will be unable to install any drivers on the server side, and i will only be able to make changes/Install what is required on the client.

Comment: It might be useful to tag the question with Solaris as well.

Comment: Take a look at this link. Probably helps. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly you are trying to connect to a MySql database from c#. This can be achieved by downloading the .net connector for MySql - [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). When you install this driver it will "integrate" with Visual Studio and you will be able to connect to the server directly from Visual Studio and your Program that will use the driver.

On the question on the syntax to connect you will either need to use MySqlConnection, with a tutorial here - http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html, or use something like the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx). But that depends on your Tastes.

I am assuming this Server can be access over the network.

**Update User Confused about Connection String**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

You pass that string to the connection without any JDBC:// prefixes.

**Please Note haven't done this in a while so the connection string could be wrong (So correct me If I'm wrong) and if you forget any connection string in the future you can always use a website like http://www.connectionstrings.com/ which shows them all for you. That is where I got the string above.**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ive Installed the drivers, and the syntax looks ok, however I am unable to actually connect to the database the url that i normally use in java is something like jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.10:1111/history, ive tryed entering this in the server= area but im still seeing errors, ive tried entering it in a number of ways, mysql://ip, just the ip ect. any suggestions? ps. sorry for the bad spelling

Comment: Yes that connection strings are quite diffrent. The connection string you used was according to Java's JDBC driver. See above for connection string structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want to connect (on the server): 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html

You can try your connection like this:

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=yourserver;" +
                "DATABASE=mydatabase;" +
                "UID=testuser;" +
                "PASSWORD=testpassword;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
```

You would probably want to follow the normal guidelines for IDisposable classes (use using etc.).

Answer (score -1):

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows;
   class Connexion
{
    public MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connexion;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password; 



    public Connexion()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "GestionCommeriale";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        String connexionString;
        connexionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" +
        "UID" + uid + ";" + "PASSSWORD =" + password + ";";
        connexion = new MySqlConnection(connexionString);
    }



    public bool OpenConnexion()
```

{
       try
       {
           connexion.Open();
           return true;
       }
       catch (MySqlException ex)
       {
           switch (ex.Number)
           {
               case 0:
                   MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                   break;
               case 1045:
                   MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                   break;
            }
           return false;
       }
   }

```
    public bool ColseConnexion()
```

{
       try
       {
           connexion.Close();
           return true;
       }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
      }

```
}
```

}